# Why are alkyl halides immiscible with water?

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides

Why are alkyl halides, though polar, immiscible with water?

I have tried to solve this question by myself and I believe that it's due to the large energy is needed to break the hydrogen bonds, which is insufficient to overcome the forces present in water. But I'm not sure if I'm right. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Think about the energy considerations for a substance to get dissolved.